# materializecss footer bottom

Tags: html, css, angularjs, materialize

I am using materializecss (angular-materialize) and I have many pages where my footer isn't at the bottom. In the website they say that we have to follow the html structure below and to add some css code :

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
        </header>
        <main>
        </main>
        <footer>
        </footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS code added from the website :

```
body {
    display: flex;
    min-height: 100vh;
    flex-direction: column;
  }

  main {
    flex: 1 0 auto;
  }
```

Even if I follow the steps, my footer doesn't want to go down.

If someone could help :)

Comment: please provide a plunkr or SO code snippet

Comment: You might be doing the structure in `angular selector` thats why it takes only required height. Try the code on `index.html` and it works.

Answer (score 0):

```
footer{
   position: static;
   bottom: 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Usually when my footers aren't sticking to the bottom, I make the margin-bottom negative pixels and then increase the margin bottom of the closest element to the footer. Messing around with margins usually fixes my problems, hope that helps!